# Power Query - how to insert text for certain rows?

Tags: powerquery

[image]

Hello,

I have a situation where I work with Medical Device UDI number. (I used dummy numbers as the information i use is client specific)

The UDI numbers are given to us as a list and we have to input it in Excel. In the photo, I list the Product Name, Item number and lots (Yellow coded) and the next section is Product Name with the corresponding UDI (Orange coded) and the list repeats like that.

As you can see, the entries differ as it can contain one or more numerical values for either the lots or the UDI number. My question is how can I insert the list of UDI numbers and input them after each Yellow section instead of copying and pasting? I hope that helps.

I am still new in using Power Query. I saw formulas about Table Transform but I need a specific formula to insert different areas so I'm still a beginner unfortunately.

Comment: You would probably use one of the `Table.Join` functions. Pleae edit your question to 1)Provide your source data as text which can be copy/pasted, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables); 2) Indicate where this list of UDI #'s is; provide a text example; 3) Provide a screenshot of yourd expected data output from the input you provided. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So... it looks like you have a one-to-many relationship of Item Number to Lots, and ... is the UDI number related at all? You've pasted what you want it to look like, correct? What does your source data look like?